# Реверс строки с сохранением позиций слов и спец. символов

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать реверс с сохранением слов и символов *( , `,`, `!`)*

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    // Заданная строка
    strint temp = "ffsd!f jgh1!ff"
    // Нужно получить 
    result = "fdsf!f ff1h!gj"

}
```

Мой результат:

```
public class Anagram {
    private string someText = default;

    public Anagram() {
        someText = "1234 5!678";

    }

    private string ReverseWord(string someString) {

        int index = 0;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Length = someString.Length;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someString));

        }
        else {

            for (int i = someString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(someString[i])) {
                    stringBuilder.Insert(index, someString[i]);
                }
                else {

                    stringBuilder.Insert(i, someString[i]);
                }

                index++;
            }
        }

        string result = stringBuilder.ToString();
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: А вопрос ваш в чем? или вы зашли похвастаться кодом?

Comment: вопрос в том что у меня не получается сохранять порядок слов при реверсе. прошу прощения если не правильно написал в чем у меня вопрос

Comment: разбейте предложение на слова `string[] words = text.Split();` и работайте с каждыйм словом отдельно, затем соберите строку обратно, разделив пробелами `text = string.Join(" ", words)`.

Comment: @aepot, тут другая задача. Посмотри какой пример приведен. А может и не совсем другая :)

Comment: по идее правильно , нужно разбить по словам , сделать реверс и собрать строку обратно но теперь проблема в другом не понимаю как делать реверс с сохранением к примеру '!' на своем месте

Comment: делаю сплит получаю массив слов потом цикле создаю два массива char , один для заполнения второй потом для реверса и вот как сделать правильно реверс не пойму

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    char[] word = new char[array[i].Length];
                    char[] wordRevers = new char[array[i].Length];

                    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        word[j] = array[i][j];  

                    }

Comment: @SergiiKushnarenko split не обязателен, ты и так можешь получить символ по индексу

Comment: Все равно не получается сделать . У меня два массива char в цикле (в одном слово посимвольно записано к примеру 's' 't' 'r' '!' 'n' 'g') . Как мне сделать реверс из одного массива в другой с сохранением позиции "!"    ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот достаточно простое решение "в лоб".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "ffsd!f jgh1!ff";
    string result = ReverseText(text);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static string ReverseText(string text)
{
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].Length > 1)
        {
            words[i] = ReverseWord(words[i]);
        }
    }
    return string.Join(" ", words);
}

static string ReverseWord(string word)
{
    char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
            
    int j = word.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(word[i]))
        {
            while (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(word[j]))
            {
                j--;
            }
            chars[j] = word[i];
            j--;
        }
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Не стесняйтесь разбивать свое решение на методы, тогда не придется забивать голову всем сразу.

```
fdsf!f ff1h!gj
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: `while (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(word[j]))` тут можно исключение получить, если в строке ни одной буквы не будет

Comment: @Grundy не будет, так как если до этого условия дошло, то буква точно есть.

Comment: логично, до `word[i]` дойдет только