# Перевернуть слово не меняя его порядок

Tags: c#, wpf

Массив и цикл меняет слово задом на перед, но при нескольких словах можно заметить, что оно меняет и порядок слов. Как оставить слова задом на перед на своём месте?

```
string data = TextBox_1.Text;
char[] charc = data.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(charc);
int i;
string emptystr = string.Empty;
for (i = 0; i < charc.Length; i++)
{
    emptystr += charc[i];
}
TextBox_2.Text = emptystr.ToString();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: c# wpf - подписал!

Comment: Смотрите методы структуры [Char](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-6.0). Вам могут понадобиться `IsLetter`, `IsPunctuation` и т. п.

Comment: К чему здесь вообще приплетены wpf, textbox и прочее? Ваша задача: перевернуть отдельные слова, не меняя их порядок. Отредактируйте вопрос, удалив всё лишнее.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1417817/373567